# Using JMX MBean, how to customize notification fields in JConsole

Tags: java, jmx, jconsole, mbeans

After googling around this subject, I did not find much information about JMX Mbean Notifications.

- Official doc : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/notifs/index.html
- Old doc (2002) : http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=27842&seqNum=5

I have setup a MBean using **NotificationBroadcasterSupport** class. As I am sending **Notification**, I can see in the JConsole the default fields : "*TimeStamp*", "*Type*", "*UserData*", "*SeqNum*", "*Message*", "*Event*", and "*Source*"

In the Jconsole Notification buffer output, I would like to configure the fields :

- Is it possible to hide some fields ?
- Is it possible to add new fields ?
- Sorting does not seem available in columns. Is there a way to achieve this ?

My goal is to provide statistics about actions (Each time an action is triggered, I want to print TimeStamp, Execution time, ...), but I don't want to pretty print all those information in string message. Maybe there is a better way of doing this ?